# Editing Configured Values Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am familiar with referencing nodes in powershell, but am not entirely sure how to edit the following nodes because each value does not have a unique identifier. Can I edit the values based on the path somehow? Each path references an SSIS variable. I need to edit only the configuredValue but this is across 15 nodes. Below is 2 examples of these nodes:

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Variables[User::var1].Properties[Value]" 
    ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>SomeValue</ConfiguredValue>
 </Configuration>
 <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Variables[User::var2].Properties[Value]" 
    ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>AnotherValue</ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration>
```

In the example above, I am looking to edit "someValue" based on Path, is this possible? I was originally editing by line number but soon realized the line numbers change per client file.

Ideally, I'd like to loop through all files in a filepath and do this for each individual file.

UPDATED: attached is my working code, thank you @gms0ulman!

```
$filePath = ("\\server1\test")  #location of all files

    Foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $filePath | where {!$_.PSIsContainer}){

      $xml = [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName)
      #updating attribute
      $node = $xml.root.Configuration
      ($xml.root.Configuration | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "*var1*"}).ConfiguredValue = "newValue"
      $xml.Save($file.FullName)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible:

```
# xml object to use in example
[xml]$xml = @"
<root>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Variables[User::var1].Properties[Value]" 
        ValueType="String">
            <ConfiguredValue>SomeValue</ConfiguredValue>
     </Configuration>
     <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Variables[User::var2].Properties[Value]" 
        ValueType="String">
            <ConfiguredValue>AnotherValue</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
</root>
"@
```

---

```
# standard node dot-indexing, before
$xml.root.Configuration

# ConfiguredType Path                                             ValueType ConfiguredValue
# -------------- ----                                             --------- ---------------
# Property       \Package.Variables[User::var1].Properties[Value] String    SomeValue
# Property       \Package.Variables[User::var2].Properties[Value] String    AnotherValue


# change the value based on Path
($xml.root.Configuration | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "*var1*"}).ConfiguredValue = "newValue"


# standard node dot-indexing, after
$xml.root.Configuration

# ConfiguredType Path                                             ValueType ConfiguredValue
# -------------- ----                                             --------- ---------------
# Property       \Package.Variables[User::var1].Properties[Value] String    newValue
# Property       \Package.Variables[User::var2].Properties[Value] String    AnotherValue
```

Comment: This was so helpful! Thank you for your quick response! +1